# Need a POP3 or IMAP relay or adapter from an exchange server, any ideas?

Tags: exchange, email-server, imap, pop3

**Short version of the issue**

- We have a 3rd party workflow tool that needs to check e-mail inboxes.
- The tool only supports checking e-mail with pop3 or IMAP
- Our network guys don't allow pop3 or IMAP access to our exchange server.

**My working solution / Concept**

- Install some kind of pop3/imap mail server software on the web server with the workflow tool.
- Have the workflow tool import via exchange/MAPI the e-mail for this one mailbox, then serve it up (only to the local machine for security reasons) using Pop3/IMAP so the workflow tool can check the inbox.

Essentially I need a way to "translate" or some kind of adapter to have a pop3 client talk to exchange via MAPI/Exchange protocols.

Do you know of any tool like the one I described above? Is there perhaps a better solution to the problem that I'm missing?

Answer (score 5):

I'd seriously push for fighting the political battle to allow IMAP access to the Exchange system. IMAP and POP can be enabled on a per-account basis. Since this is a workflow item with a defined business application, there's definitely a purpose...

I'd be more suspicious of a the long-term viability of a workaround solution or anything that adds more complexity to the stack.

Comment: Thanks. That is a good argument, and I was not aware that you could localize access to POP3 like that. It may still be a battle because I think they are blocking those ports on the firewalls too. I'm in a small group in a huge organization, so it may be a tough fight. I'm with you that a workaround like this is definitely not plan a.

Comment: I typically disable IMAP and POP3, but *do* enable it for my email journaling account and specific users who refuse to use Outlook. So exceptions are *technically* possible.

Comment: Update: I'm losing the battle. Still could use an answer if you have one to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late for you but I am posting an answer for posterity. Check out DavMail - http://davmail.sourceforge.net

This is a cross-platform gateway for Exchange or Office365. In their own words -

"DavMail is a POP/IMAP/SMTP/Caldav/Carddav/LDAP gateway allowing users to use any mail client with Exchange, even from the internet through Outlook Web Access on any platform, tested on MacOSX, Linux and Windows"